# Implementation of FFT array

Tags: android, fft

I have a problem when implementing a FFT algorithm in Android.
Let´s say that I have a wav file of 8.000 bytes length.
I am aware that you have to select a size of the FFT algorithm (and also has to be a power of 2). My problem is that I am not really sure about how to further proceed from now on.
Lets say that I have chosen a size of the FFT of N=1024.
I have basically to options on my mind:
1) Apply the FFT algorithm directly to the whole array of 8.000 bytes
2) Divide the 8000 byte array wav file in chunks of 1024 bytes (and fill with 0´s the last chunk untill having 8 exact chunks),
then apply the fft to each of this chunks and finally collate all the different chunks again to have one single byte array to represent.
8000*2*1 sec = 8192

I think it´s the option 2 but I am not completely sure.

Here is the fft array thaT I am using:

```
package com.example.acoustics;

public class FFT {

  int n, m;

  // Lookup tables. Only need to recompute when size of FFT changes.
  double[] cos;
  double[] sin;

  public FFT(int n) {
      this.n = n;
      this.m = (int) (Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));

      // Make sure n is a power of 2
      if (n != (1 << m))
          throw new RuntimeException("FFT length must be power of 2");

      // precompute tables
      cos = new double[n / 2];
      sin = new double[n / 2];

      for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
          cos[i] = Math.cos(-2 * Math.PI * i / n);
          sin[i] = Math.sin(-2 * Math.PI * i / n);
      }

  }

  /***************************************************************
     * fft.c
     * Douglas L. Jones 
     * University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign 
     * January 19, 1992 
     * http://cnx.rice.edu/content/m12016/latest/
     * 
     *   fft: in-place radix-2 DIT DFT of a complex input 
     * 
     *   input: 
     * n: length of FFT: must be a power of two 
     * m: n = 2**m 
     *   input/output 
     * x: double array of length n with real part of data 
     * y: double array of length n with imag part of data 
     * 
     *   Permission to copy and use this program is granted 
     *   as long as this header is included. 
     ****************************************************************/

  public void fft(double[] x, double[] y) {
      int i, j, k, n1, n2, a;
      double c, s, t1, t2;

      // Bit-reverse
      j = 0;
      n2 = n / 2;
      for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
          n1 = n2;
          while (j >= n1) {
              j = j - n1;
              n1 = n1 / 2;
          }
          j = j + n1;

          if (i < j) {
              t1 = x[i];
              x[i] = x[j];
              x[j] = t1;
              t1 = y[i];
              y[i] = y[j];
              y[j] = t1;
          }
      }

      // FFT
      n1 = 0;
      n2 = 1;

      for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
          n1 = n2;
          n2 = n2 + n2;
          a = 0;

          for (j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
              c = cos[a];
              s = sin[a];
              a += 1 << (m - i - 1);

              for (k = j; k < n; k = k + n2) {
                  t1 = c * x[k + n1] - s * y[k + n1];
                  t2 = s * x[k + n1] + c * y[k + n1];
                  x[k + n1] = x[k] - t1;
                  y[k + n1] = y[k] - t2;
                  x[k] = x[k] + t1;
                  y[k] = y[k] + t2;
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the result of the FFT? For most practical applications you would divide the data array into overlapping blocks, apply windowing, do the FFT, do the filtering/modification, do the inverse FFT and add the results using the same overlap structure. The windowing can be arranged to be a division of unity, so that without modifications the original array is obtained as result of these operations.

Comment: I am trying to plot the FFT spectrum like these one:       [Plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/periodogram_psd.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the entire array with the FFT. There is not problem with that, you can use 2^13 = 8192 and complete the array with zeros, this processing is also called zero padding and is used in more than one implementation of the FFT. If your procedure works well there is not problem with run the entire array, but if you use section of size 1024 for compute the FFT, then you will have a segmented Fourier transform that not describe well the entire spectrum of the signal, because the FFT use all the positions in the array to compute each value in the new transformed array, then you not get the correct answer in the position one for example if you don't use the entire array of the signal.

This is my analysis of your question I am not hundred percent sure but my knowledge about Fourier series tell me that this is almost that is going to do if you compute a segmented form of the Fourier Transform instead the entire serie.

Comment: Yes, it is better to use the whole thing when feasible.  However, I think the padding number should be the average value of the inputs. Or normalize the data before padding with zeros. Am I wrong? The idea, as I see it, is to make it look like the sound trailed off to silence. If there is a DC offset, silence is not zero.